# Why is it right to use the word "from" to say "there was no place free from them"

Tags: semantics

I would use the word "of" as the word "from" indicates origin so it sounds a bit weird.
I read this in a periodical from JSTOR talking about immigration to the old border states.

Comment: We say: The garden was full of bugs. No corner of it was free from them. Applied to people, it sounds slightly racist.

Comment: [**from**, Definition 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from): used as a function word to indicate physical separation or an act or condition of removal, abstention, exclusion, release, subtraction, or differentiation; protection *from* the sun, relief *from* anxiety

Answer (score 1):

The simple and complete (though possibly unsatisfying) answer is that the adjective "free" in this sense correlates with the preposition "from".

The meaning of "free" in this context from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/free) is:

> **4 a :** relieved from or lacking something and especially something unpleasant or burdensome

This means if you use "free" in this sense, then "from" is one of the correct prepositions to connect "free" to its object.

There is no grammatical reason beyond that. There are etymological roots to that correlation, but etymology isn't grammar.

Comment: Sometimes *free of* can be substituted -  *Free from mosquitos* and *Free of mosquitos.*  Am I free *from* mosquitos while my backyard is free *of* mosquitos?  Sometimes it cannot be substituted.  *Free from the drudgery of housework* and *Free of the drudgery of housework*.  Or does that work too?

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I chose not to mention "free of" in my answer because it's tangential to a question about "from", but I was careful to say that "from" is ***one of** the correct prepositions*.

Answer (score 1):

Bryan Garner asserts, in his *Dictionary of Legal Usage*, that both *free from* and *free of* are correct but also notes a distinction with the noun form: We speak of *freedom from* something unpleasant or onerous (*freedom from oppression, pestilence, coercion*) but use *of* with something neutral or beneficial (*freedom of speech*). (Also *free of charge*.)

I suggest that the distinction should also be maintained with *free from* [something onerous] and *free of* [something neutral or beneficial], given that readers have unconsciously stored the distinction noted above.